# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.wepay.android.internal.Swiper

Tags: java, android, wepay

I'm working on integrating WePay Java SDK in Android Studio.

Using following class for WePay initialization:

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import com.wepay.android.SignatureHandler;
import com.wepay.android.SwiperHandler;
import com.wepay.android.TokenizationHandler;
import com.wepay.android.WePay;
import com.wepay.android.models.Config;
import com.wepay.android.models.PaymentInfo;

/**
* Created by zachv on 7/27/15.
* Wecrowd Android
*/
public class PaymentManager {

private static Config config = null;
private static WePay wepay = null;
private static String clientId = "";

public PaymentManager(String clientId) {
    //this.clientId = clientId;
}

public static void tokenizeInfo(Context context, PaymentInfo paymentInfo,
                                final TokenizationHandler handler) {
    initializeMembersFromContext(context);

    wepay.tokenize(paymentInfo, handler);
}

public static void startCardSwipeTokenization(Context context, SwiperHandler swiperHandler,
                                              TokenizationHandler tokenizationHandler)
{
    initializeMembersFromContext(context);

    wepay.startSwiperForTokenizing(swiperHandler, tokenizationHandler);
}

public static void stopCardReader(Context context) {
    initializeMembersFromContext(context);

    wepay.stopSwiper();
}

public static void storeSignatureImage(Context context,
                                       Bitmap image,
                                       String checkoutID,
                                       SignatureHandler signatureHandler)
{
    initializeMembersFromContext(context);

    wepay.storeSignatureImage(image, checkoutID, signatureHandler);
}

private static void initializeMembersFromContext(Context context) {
    if (config == null || wepay == null) {
        config = new Config(context, clientId, Config.ENVIRONMENT_STAGING);
        config.setRestartSwiperAfterSwipeGeneralError(true);
        wepay = new WePay(config);
    } else if (config.getContext() != context) {
        config = new Config(context, clientId, Config.ENVIRONMENT_STAGING);
        config.setRestartSwiperAfterSwipeGeneralError(true);
        wepay = new WePay(config);
    }
}
 }
```

Now when the function 
     initializeMembersFromContext

is called, it raises following exception:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.wepay.android.internal.Swiper
```

at this line:

```
 wepay = new WePay(config);
```

inside if block of function.
I'm passing clientId correctly to this class and all other info too.

I'm a complete noob to WePay in Android.
Please suggest.

Comment: It seems the `Swiper` class is not present in the APK. How do you declare the dependency to the WePay SDK? Do you have multidex enabled?

Comment: I've added wepay.jar to my libs folder

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` script? At least to know how you declared your dependencies and if you have `multidex` enabled. Thanks.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.11.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/wepay.jar')
}